# How to delete elements from two lists upon contact?

Tags: c++, list

I'm having an incredibly difficult time programming Space Invaders for a class.  I am supposed to use a list to store my "missiles" and a list to store my "aliens" as well.  I press space bar to load in a new alien, and when the two contact, I am attempting to delete both of them, and I can't even get past deleting the "alien".  I get a variety of bugs when more than one missile is fired, and the missiles work fine if this function is commented out.  I am forced to pass a list of missiles into another class that already contains a list of aliens and delete both.

Here is the offending code:

```
bool AlienMgr::checkHit(PlayerMgr& playerMgr)
{

    bool hit = false; // If the player hits an alien, switches to true and is returned.
    list<Missile*>::iterator missileIter;
    list<Missile*> missileList = playerMgr.getMissiles();
    int missileCount;

    FloatRect missileBounds;
    FloatRect alienBounds;

    iter = myAliens.begin();

    while (!myAliens.empty() && iter != myAliens.end())
    {
        alienBounds = (*iter)->getGlobalBounds();

        if (!missileList.empty() && !hit)
        {

            for (missileIter = missileList.begin(); missileIter != missileList.end() && !hit; missileIter++)
            {
                missileBounds = (*missileIter)->getMissileBounds();

                if (alienBounds.intersects(missileBounds))
                {
                    delete (*iter);
                    iter = myAliens.erase(iter);
                    cout << "HIT" << endl;

                }
                else
                {
                    iter++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            iter++;
        }
    }
    return hit;
}
```

Comment: *If the player hits an alien, switches to true and is returned.* - No, it doesn't switch to true. That's what the comment says, but that's not what happens in the code :). Also before making any fixes - move variable declarations to where they are initialized; declaring them all at the beginning of a function is bad, obsolete practice. Similarly, you shouldn't manually manage the lifetime of your objects; storing values would prevent you from having to `delete` them. Clearing out the noise will help you focus on actual problem you're having.

Comment: If you want to remove an alien and all the missiles it collides with you need to remove the missiles before you remove the alien.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code. I've tried to clean them up. Also, I hope you can use c++ 11.

```
bool AlienMgr::checkHit(PlayerMgr& playerMgr)
{

    bool hit = false; // If the player hits an alien, switches to true and is returned.
    list<Missile*> missileList = playerMgr.getMissiles();
    int missileCount;

    FloatRect missileBounds;
    FloatRect alienBounds;

    // iter == myAliens.end() if it's empty
    for (auto iter = myAliens.begin(); iter != myAliens.end();)
    {
        bool hitDetected = false;
        alienBounds = (*iter)->getGlobalBounds();

        // remove all missiles intersecting current alien and set flag
        missileList.remove_if([&](Missile* missile)
            {
                if (!alienBounds.intersects(missile->getMissileBounds()))
                    return false;

                hitDetected = true;
                delete missile;

                return true;
            });

        if (hitDetected)
        {
            hit = true;

            delete (*iter);
            iter = myAliens.erase(iter);
            cout << "HIT" << endl;
        else
        {
            iter++;
        }
    }
    return hit;
}
```

However, there are more critical problems. Your code is too c++98'ish.
I would advise several improvements:

- Use `std::vector` instead of `std::list` (it's **really** hard to find case when list will be faster)
- Use smart pointers instead of manual memory management (code would be much simple and easier to understand)